# AWS registered domain IP not resolvable when routing to S3 static hosted site, domain name server matches hosted zone name server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to make my s3 static website available through my aws registered domain but seem to have run into some issues. The domain is kammryndancy.com and the s3 static website is available through http://kammryndancy.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/. I created the hosted zone for kammryndancy.com the configuration is as such [image: hosted zone]

I updated my registered domain name servers to match the hosted zone, and appear as such [image]

When I run `dig +norecurse @a.gtld-servers.net kammryndancy.com` I get what appears to be the appropriate response.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> +norecurse @a.gtld-servers.net kammryndancy.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31582
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kammryndancy.com.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
kammryndancy.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-80.awsdns-10.com.
kammryndancy.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-966.awsdns-56.net.
kammryndancy.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-1449.awsdns-53.org.
kammryndancy.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-1942.awsdns-50.co.uk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-80.awsdns-10.com.    172800  IN  A   205.251.192.80

;; Query time: 111 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 23 23:55:53 MDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 197
```

I am not sure why when I enter the domain in a browser it consistently responds with ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, this is in chrome, chrome incognito, firefox, firefox private. I followed the numerous tutorials for setting up a domain to redirect to static website but havent had any success. Anyone have an idea where I went wrong?